# Unusual bad program performance in Java

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, optimization, arraylist

I'm a novice programmer, I'm make my first game in Java, and I just implemented a target AI, and now whenever I run it, always lags at start, I would like a explanation on why please or a way to do this better, Thank you in advance.

Code:(for what is most Likely causing the lag)

```
public class Handler {
//Use Linked Lists
private Animator a;
private boolean renderMini;
private int x, y;
public LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();
public LinkedList<EntityObject> entity = new LinkedList<EntityObject>();
public LinkedList<Faction> faction = new LinkedList<Faction>();

public Handler(){
    a = new Animator();
    this.renderMini = false;
}

public void render(Graphics g){
    ///if(GameMain.numFrames > 5){
        if(renderMini){
            a.AnimateMini(g, x, y, 32, 32);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < entity.size(); i++){
            EntityObject tempObject = entity.get(i);

            tempObject.render(g);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.render(g);
        }
    //}
}

public void tick(){ 
    //if(GameMain.numFrames > 5){
        for(int i = 0; i < entity.size(); i++){
            EntityObject tempObject = entity.get(i);
            tempObject.tick();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.tick();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < faction.size(); i++){
            Faction tempObject = faction.get(i);

            tempObject.tick();
        }
    //}
}   
public void addEntity(EntityObject o){
    this.entity.add(o);
}

public void removeEntity(EntityObject o){
    this.entity.remove(o);
}

public void addObject(GameObject o){
    this.object.add(o);
}

public void removeObject(GameObject o){
    if(o instanceof NpcLaser){
        x = o.getX();
        y = o.getY();
        renderMini = true;
    }
    if(o instanceof PlayerLaser){
        x = o.getX();
        y = o.getY();
        renderMini = true;
    }
    this.object.remove(o);
}

public void addFaction(Faction f){
    this.faction.add(f);
}

public void removeFaction(Faction f){
    this.faction.remove(f);
}
```

}

```
public class StandardShip extends EntityObject{
private Handler h;
private Random r;
private Animator a;
private Faction ef;
private EntityObject object;
private int desX, desY;
private int  lx, ly, targetX, targetY; //target;
private boolean animateReady;
public static int isDead, ran, ra, rn;
public static boolean thisDeath;
public static boolean choAttack, choDefense, choSpeed, choShealth, choCommanding;


public StandardShip(int x, int y, int width, int height, Handler h, Faction f) {
    super(x, y, width, height, h);

    r = new Random();

    a = new Animator();

    this.setDeath(false);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.h = h;
    /*this.isDead = 0;
    this.thisDeath = false;
    this.p = p;*/
    this.health = 100;
    this.animateReady = false;
    //this.target = 1;
    this.killLim = r.nextInt(4) + 1;
    EntityObject.f = f;
    EntityObject.f.addMember(this);

    this.attackLim = 20;
    this.defenseLim = 20;
    this.speedLim = 20;
    this.shealthLim = 20;
    this.commandingLim = 20;
    this.currency = 0;

    this.attack = r.nextInt(attackLim);
    this.defense = r.nextInt(defenseLim) + 1;
    this.speed = r.nextInt(speedLim) + 2;
    this.shealth = r.nextInt(shealthLim);
    this.commanding = r.nextInt(commandingLim);

    this.velX = 1;
    this.velY = 1;
    this.SearchTime = 1000;
    this.desX = r.nextInt(Window.screensize.width + 1000);
    this.desY = r.nextInt(Window.screensize.height + 1000);
    //this.vectW = 5;
    rn = r.nextInt(5);

    if(rn == 0){
        if(attack < 15){
            attack = r.nextInt(attackLim) + 15;
        }
    }
    if(rn == 1){
        if(defense < 15){
            defense = r.nextInt(defenseLim) + 15;
        }
    }
    if(rn == 2){
        if(speed < 15){
            speed = r.nextInt(speedLim) + 15;
        }
    }
    if(rn == 3){
        if(shealth < 15){
            shealth = r.nextInt(shealthLim) + 15;
        }
    }
    if(rn == 4){
        if(commanding < 15){
            commanding = r.nextInt(commandingLim) + 15;
        }
    }

    if(choAttack){
        if(attack < 15){
            attack = r.nextInt(attackLim) + 15;
        }
    }
    if(choDefense){
        if(defense < 15){
            defense = r.nextInt(defenseLim) + 15;
        }
    }
    if(choSpeed){
        if(speed < 15){
            speed = r.nextInt(speedLim) + 15;
        }

    }
    if(choShealth){
        if(shealth < 15){
            shealth = r.nextInt(shealthLim) + 15;
        }
    }
    if(choCommanding){
        if(commanding < 15){
            commanding = r.nextInt(commandingLim) + 15;
        }

    }
}


public void tick() {
    x = GameMain.clamp(0, Window.screensize.width + 1000, x);
    y = GameMain.clamp(0, Window.screensize.height + 1000, y);
    x += velX;
    y += velY;
    EnemySize = f.isEnemy.size();
    if(coolDown > 0){
        coolDown--;
        coolDown = GameMain.clamp(0, 1000, coolDown);
    }
    if(this.target == null){
        for(int i = 0; i < EnemySize; i++){
            ef = EntityObject.f.isEnemy.get(i);
            memberSize = ef.members.size();
        }   
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < ef.members.size(); i++){
        object = ef.members.get(i);

        if(object.getX() >= this.x && object.getX() <= this.x + 300){
            this.setTarget(object);
            System.out.println("TargetSS");
            i = ef.members.size();
        }
        if(object.getY() >= this.y && object.getY() <= this.y + 300){
            this.setTarget(object);
            System.out.println("TargetSS");
            i = ef.members.size();
        }
    }
    if(this.target != null && coolDown <= 0){
        targetX = this.target.getX();
        targetY = this.target.getY();
        attack(targetX, targetY);
        coolDown = 500;
    }
    if(this.target == null){
        wander();
    }
    /*rand = r.nextInt(100);
    if(kills == killLim){
        level++;
        levelUp();
        kills = 0;
        killLim += killLim/2;
    }

    x += velX;
    y += velY;

    if(y < vectY && velY == -1){velY *= -1;}
    if(y > vectY && velY == 1){velY *= -1;}
    if(x < vectX && velX == -1){velX *= -1;}
    if(x > vectX && velX == 1){velX *= -1;}
    if(x == vectX){
        if(r.nextInt(2) == 0){
            vectX = r.nextInt(Window.screensize.width);
        }else{
            velX = 0;
        }
    }
    if(y == vectY){
        if(r.nextInt(2) == 0){
            vectY = r.nextInt(Window.screensize.height);
        }else{
            velY = 0;
        }
    }*/


    if(this.isDamage > 0 && this.isDamage > defense){
        health -= isDamage - (defense / 2);
        isDamage = 0;
        //System.out.println("HELLO");
    }
}

public void wander(){
    if(y < desY && velY == -1){velY *= -1;}
    if(y > desY && velY == 1){velY *= -1;}
    if(x < desX && velX == -1){velX *= -1;}
    if(x > desX && velX == 1){velX *= -1;}

    System.out.println("desY: "+desY+" desX: "
            +desX+" Y: "+y+" X: "+x+" velX: "+velX+" velY: "+velY);

    if(x == desX){
        //if(r.nextInt(2) == 0){
            desX = r.nextInt(Window.screensize.width + 1000);
        //}else{
            velX = 0;
        //}
    }
    if(y == desY){
        //if(r.nextInt(2) == 0){
            desY = r.nextInt(Window.screensize.height + 1000);
        //}else{
            velY = 0;
        //}
    }
}

public void levelUp(){
    this.health +=  r.nextInt(300) + 100;
    this.attack += r.nextInt(attackLim);
    this.defense += r.nextInt(defenseLim) + 1;
    this.speed += r.nextInt(speedLim) + 2;
    this.shealth += r.nextInt(shealthLim);
    this.commanding += r.nextInt(commandingLim);


    if(choAttack){
        attack += (r.nextInt(attackLim) + 15)/2;
    }
    if(choDefense){
        defense += (r.nextInt(defenseLim) + 15)/2;
    }
    if(choSpeed){
        speed += (r.nextInt(speedLim) + 15)/2;
    }
    if(choShealth){
        shealth += (r.nextInt(shealthLim) + 15)/2;
    }
    if(choCommanding){
        commanding += (r.nextInt(commandingLim) + 15)/2;    
    }
}

public void Collision(Graphics g){
    /*for(int i = 0; i < h.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = h.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Money){
            Money m = (Money) tempObject;
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){
                currency += m.getCashValue();
                h.removeObject(tempObject);
            }
        }
        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.ShipPart){
            ShipPart s = (ShipPart) tempObject;
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){
                numShipParts++;
                h.removeObject(tempObject);
            }
        }
        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Meteor){
            Meteor m = (Meteor) tempObject;
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){
                Rectangle OverLap = getBounds().intersection(tempObject.getBounds());
                if(OverLap.height >= OverLap.width){
                    if(m.isDoesDamage() && !m.isExplodes() && !m.isOnFire()){
                        this.health -= m.getDamage();
                        velX *= -2;
                    }
                    if(m.isDoesDamage() && m.isExplodes() || m.isDoesDamage() && m.isOnFire()){
                        if(m.isExplodes()){
                            a.AnimateExplosion(g, tempObject.getX(), tempObject.getY(), 32, 32);
                            this.health -= m.getDamage();
                            if(a.isFin[0]){
                                h.removeObject(tempObject);
                                a.isFin[0] = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if(m.isOnFire()){
                            this.health -= m.getDamage();
                            velX *= -2;
                        }
                    }else{
                        velX *= -2;
                    }
                }
                if(OverLap.width >= OverLap.height){
                    if(m.isDoesDamage() && !m.isExplodes() && !m.isOnFire()){
                        this.health -= m.getDamage();
                        velY *= -2;
                    }
                    if(m.isDoesDamage() && m.isExplodes() || m.isDoesDamage() && m.isOnFire()){
                        if(m.isExplodes()){
                            this.health -= m.getDamage();
                            m.setExplodeNow(true);
                        }
                        if(m.isOnFire()){
                            this.health -= m.getDamage();
                            velY *= -2;
                        }
                    }else{
                        velY *= -2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
            p = (Player) tempObject;
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){
                Rectangle OverLap = getBounds().intersection(tempObject.getBounds());
                health -= r.nextInt(10) + 10;
                p.setDamage(r.nextInt(10) + 10);
                if(OverLap.height >= OverLap.width){
                    tempObject.setVelX(0);
                }
                if(OverLap.width >= OverLap.height){
                    tempObject.setVelY(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }*/
}

public void attack(int targetX, int targetY){

    System.out.println("Hello");
    h.addObject(new NpcLaser(x + 60, y + 60, 5, 9, h, f, targetX, targetY, this.attack));
}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    a.AnimateEnemy(g, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, f);
    if(animateReady){
        a.AnimateMini(g, lx, ly, ran, ran);
    }
    if(health <= 0){
        setDeath(true);
        StandardShip.thisDeath = true;
        a.AnimateExplosion(g, x, y, width, height);

        if(Animator.isFin[0]){
            ra = r.nextInt(10);

            isDead++;

            if(ra <= 7){
                h.addObject(new Money(x, y, 32, 32, ID.Money, h, currency));
            }else{
                for(int i = 0; i < numShipParts; i++){
                    h.addObject(new ShipPart(x, y, 32, 32, ID.ShipPart, h));
                }
            }
            h.removeEntity(this);
            Animator.isFin[0] = false;
        }
    }
    g.setColor(Color.red);
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x + 40, y + 37, 50, 50);
}
```

}

```
public class NpcLaser extends GameObject{
private Handler h;
private Faction f, ef;
private int laserAim;
private int currentTarget;
private int vectorX, vectorY;
private int damage;

public NpcLaser(int x, int y, int width, int height, Handler h, Faction f, int targetX, int targetY, int attack) {
    super(x, y, width, height, h);

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.h = h;
    this.f = f;
    this.vectorX = targetX;
    this.vectorY = targetY;
    this.damage = attack;
    new Animator();

    aimAI();
}


public void tick() {

    System.out.println("Hello");
    //Collision(g);
    x += velX;
    y += velY;

    if(velX == 0 && velY == 0){
        h.object.remove();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < f.isEnemy.size(); i++){
        ef = f.isEnemy.get(i);
    }


    for(int u = 0; u < ef.members.size(); u++){
        EntityObject eo = ef.members.get(u);

        if(getBounds().intersects(eo.getBounds())){
            eo.setDamage(damage);
            h.removeObject(this);
        }
    }

    if(x > Window.screensize.getWidth() + 1200 || x < 0 - 1200){
        h.removeObject(this);
    }
    if(y > Window.screensize.getHeight() + 1200 || y < 0 - 1200){
        h.removeObject(this);
    }
}

public void aimAI(){
    if(x < vectorX){velX = 10;}
    if(x > vectorX){velX = -10;}
    if(y < vectorY){velY = 10;}
    if(y > vectorY){velY = -10;}
    if(x <= vectorX + 60 && x >= vectorX - 60){velX = 0;}
    if(y <= vectorY + 60 && y >= vectorY - 60){velY = 0;}
}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    /*if(p.isRemoveShot()){
        h.removeObject(this);
        p.setRemoveShot(false);
    }*/
    if(velX == 10 && velY == 10 || velX == -10 && velY == -10){
        laserAim = 3;
    }
    if(velX == 10 && velY == -10 || velX == -10 && velY == 10){
        laserAim = 2;
    }
    if(velX == 10 && velY == 0 || velX == -10 && velY == 0){
        laserAim = 1;
    }
    if(velX == 0 && velY == 10 || velX == 0 && velY == -10){
        laserAim = 0;
    }

    if(laserAim == 0){
        g.drawImage(Assets.playerLaser, x, y, width, height, null);
    }
    if(laserAim == 1){
        g.drawImage(Assets.playerLaser1, x, y, width, height, null);
    }
    if(laserAim == 2){
        g.drawImage(Assets.playerLaser2, x, y, width, height, null);
    }
    if(laserAim == 3){
        g.drawImage(Assets.playerLaser3, x, y, width, height, null);
    }
}



public int getDamage() {
    return damage;
}


public void setDamage(int damage) {
    this.damage = damage;
}


public int getCurrentTarget() {
    return currentTarget;
}


public void setCurrentTarget(int currentTarget) {
    this.currentTarget = currentTarget;
}


public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
}
```

}

[Full Source Code Here](https://github.com/RentaroSatomi520/SpaceFighter)

Comment: Code dumps don't really do well on Stack Overflow.  Is there a particular piece of this code that you know has a bottlekneck?  Can you describe your methodology so that we don't have to sift through your code to figure it out?  Maybe try on Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow, and I didn't know. I'll keep that in mind of I ever post again.

Answer (score 5):

```
for(int i = 0; i < entity.size(); i++){
        EntityObject tempObject = entity.get(i);

        tempObject.render(g);
}
```

Your code includes several loops that look like this, and each take quadratic time, because they're running over `LinkedList`, which requires `O(n)` time for `get`.  You should almost certainly be using an `ArrayList`, or at minimum, using a for-each loop, e.g.

```
for (EntityObject tempObject : entity) {
  tempObject.render(g);
}
```

Comment: If the Iteration was done correctly using an ArrayList would be no different to using a LinkedList. ArrayLists are better for random access, not iteration.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, a for loop was how I learned how to do this.

Comment: @BevynQ: That's not how things work in practice.  ArrayLists get you significantly better memory locality and the like.  It's O(n) in both cases, but the constant factors are very different.

Comment: Hmm, now I seems to getting a error:Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
 at com.rentarosato520.spacefighter.engine.Handler.tick(Handler.java:49)
 at com.rentarosato520.spacefighter.GameSession.tick(GameSession.java:169)
 at com.rentarosato520.spacefighter.engine.GameMain.tick(GameMain.java:138)
 at com.rentarosato520.spacefighter.engine.GameMain.run(GameMain.java:93)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: That's what happens when you modify a collection while looping over it.  Your previous implementation would have not thrown an exception, but it also probably would have silently had ambiguous behavior or you would have had loops arbitrarily skipping elements you didn't intend to be skipped.  Please ask about that in a different question, as it's a different issue.